# Dojo layout manager

Tags: javascript, layout, dojo

Is there layout manager for Dojo Toolkit that function similar to Sencha (ExtJs) or Qooxdoo layouts?

So I can do something like this:

```
var container = new Container({layout: 'hbox'});
container.addChild(new Panel(), {flex: 1});
container.addChild(new Panel(), {flex: 1});
```

Result would be two panels laid horizontally and each taking 50% of Container width. Resizing must be handled by manager of course.

I's using Dojo 1.9.

Module in AMD format would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [CSS flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) for layout. It works with dojo layout widgets without too much hassle.